# does including <execution> require linking against tbb?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, execution, std, tbb

In my project on a Ubuntu 20 platform (with g++ 9.3.0), I use the following line

```
#include <execution>
```

to support parallel processing via standard library functions. I don't include anything from TBB, the parallel execution library from Intel. But then when I build the program I get the message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/probis.dir/src/probis.cpp.o: in function `tbb::interface7::task_arena::current_thread_index()':
/usr/include/tbb/task_arena.h:449: undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_current_slot()'
```

This is easy enough to solve (as in: make the message go away) by adding `-ltbb` to the linker line. But then I have a dependency on libtbb that I did not count on.

Is this dependency expected? Is it possible to use parallel execution without installing `tbb` (but that `tbb` overrides the default setting when it is installed)?

Comment: gcc/libstdc++ implements execution language facilities in terms of libtbb. It is required in order to use this header.

Comment: Ah OK, that clears it up, thanks! So when you install the latest g++ in Linux, TBB is always also installed? Would you mind typing it as an anser, then I'll mark it "solved". It seems others were looking for this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @[n. 'pronouns' m.] rightly said, you may need libtbb in order to make your code work. You can download the Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit which contains TBB as one of the components.
Link to download Intel® oneAPI Base Toolkit:
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit/download.html

Comment: ? You can just use the libtbb-dev package for your distro. No need to install some external toolkit.

Comment: Thanks! In fact that's what I've been doing. My question was not how to get it to work (very easy with APT) but whether this is the only way / does GNU have an alternative.