# How to compile with c++ <execution> standard library

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, std, tbb

### The issue

I am trying to use the execution policies in the standard algorithm library. However, when I try to compile I get the following error message

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\pstl\parallel_backend_tbb.h:19:10: fatal error: tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory
```

After looking at various other related questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57084789/how-to-use-execution-library-in-c17) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176614/does-including-execution-require-linking-against-tbb), I understand that the `execution` library depends upon a software called `tbb`. Moreover in order to compile code which uses `<execution>` one has to manually link to `tbb`. **My issue is precisely with how to download and link** `tbb` to a script that uses `<execution>`.

I believe I have some serious gaps in my understanding in terms of how one downloads the correct files and then links to them. I will first make a list with my understanding of the linking process and then I will explain what I have tried to fix the issue. I have chosen this format so that it is faster for the one to answer my question to point at the issue at fault. I will attempt to keep this as concise as possible.

### My understanding

- Code is organized in header and `cpp` files, where the former usually only contain the interface to the software and the later the implementation
- The `cpp` files can be pre-compiled and grouped into a single library file
- For a user to then use the library, they have to `#include` the header/s in their script and also tell the compiler where the header files as well as the library file, are located
- This can be done with the `-I` for the headers and `-L`, `-l` for the library file
- `-L` provides the location of the library files, the `-l` specifies which libraries to use

### What I tried

The script I try to compile is:

```
#include <execution>

int main() {

std::execution::par;

return 0;

}
```

with

```
g++ script.cpp -o out -I C:(path to the headers) -L C:(path to the library) -l (name of library) -std=c++17
```

I should also mention I am trying to do this on Windows 10

#### 1st attempt

I had a particularly hard time understanding where to find the header and library files for `tbb`.

In the Intel [getting started with TBB](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/get-started-with-tbb.html) webpage, [this](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB) github repository is listed as "TBB being available at". As I am used to header-only libraries I thought everything would be in the include directory but no `.dll` files where there. It is now my understanding that I have to compile the DLLs myself for my specific system which makes sense. I followed the [following](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/master/INSTALL.md) process using `cmake`:

```
# Do our experiments in /tmp
cd /tmp
# Clone oneTBB repository
git clone https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB.git
cd oneTBB
# Create binary directory for out-of-source build
mkdir build && cd build
# Configure: customize CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and disable TBB_TEST to avoid tests build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/my_installed_onetbb -DTBB_TEST=OFF ..
# Build
cmake --build 
# Install
cmake --install .
# Well done! Your installed oneTBB is in /tmp/my_installed_onetbb
```

However at the `cmake --build` step, `cmake` does not accept the command but requests more options. One of them is the `dir` option, which for which I made another directory and supplied it but then the error message `Error: could not load cache` printed out.

In any case, some files had been created so I searched for the `.dll` file but could not find it.

#### 2nd attempt

I downloaded the Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176614/does-including-execution-require-linking-against-tbb). After the installation at `../Program Files (x86)/Intel/oneAPI` I found the specific `tbb` tool at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb` and I used this address for the `-I` and `-L` flags but initial error message persists.

I also copied the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\tbb\2021.6.0` to the local directory of the script so I could link with `-flag tbb\2021.6.0` but no luck

Many thanks

Comment: Don't download TBB manually. Replace your MinGW with the one from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) (which incidentally ships a more modern version). Install TBB from MSYS2 as well. Link it using `-ltbb`, and it should just work.

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Try `cmake --build .` with the dot, it is required.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did this and I got some a bit further so thanks! Having downloaded MSYS2, I can compile the above script **without** `-ltbb`. I needed to install `tbb` and I did with `pacman -S <package name>`, installing [this](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-intel-tbb). However, the g++ compiler can still not find `-ltbb`. I tried to figure out where Msys2 installs the .dll files to include this directory in the compiler but no luck, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I fixed the issue by following your comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913457/how-do-i-compile-c-code-with-boost-on-msys2) :). It turns out I was using the MSYS shell which was unable to locate the correct library. Now it compiles fine and the multithreaded test-code runs as it should (ie time reduced 9-fold). I will wait a couple of days in case you want to add something to this solution and then I will create an answer summarizing these comments. Again, many thanks!

(PS: I should mention that I must use `-ltbb12` instead of `-ltbb`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you were correct.
By using the package mingw-w64-tbb. You can use -ltbb12 instead of -ltbb. As the library files are related to ltbb12.

For using -ltbb option, you should set the Intel oneAPI environment. It can be used by downloading Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit.You can set the environment by sourcing setvars.sh file using the below command.

source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh